# Switching 12V 2A witch raspberry pi 3.3V

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi

I've bought an LED strip with 3 Colours. Each colour schould be switched individually. Sadly I couldn't find any Mosfet suiting my applecation and I'm not really good at finding Mosfet's or drawing Scematics. 
 The Mosfet should be able to:

- Switch fully on with the 3.3V from my raspberry pi
- switch up to 2A

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbRoBy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
It would be great if you could either give me an example for a suited Mosfet or Point out to me how to find the Right one!

 Thanks in Advance!

 P.S.: I'm sorry for the rude tone, but I'm not a native english speaker and not the best at it.

Comment: [Shopping questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We don't like to answer shopping questions because there's a theoretical number of possible shopping questions {number of electronic circuits ever invented|number of components on the market}. None of these can be of use for further readers. It just clogs the site. Explain why you can't skim the part selection tools of ON semicondutctors or Texas Instruments. And we can help you so you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three suggestions to choose from:

1. Look at this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/81138/250420
2. Look up logic-level MOSFETs
3. If you really want to use the MOSFET you have, there are easy circuit solutions. Here is one. Note that if you are using an LED array with built-in resistors, designed for 12V, you won't need the series resistor R3. Also, be attentive to the power deposited in that resistor, maybe divide it into several if necessary:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faA17s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is there so that if the RPi is not connected, the LEDs are off. Otherwise, it is not necessary. R4's value is chosen high enough to limit the base current of Q1, but low enough so that when the RPi GPIO voltage is low, the base voltage is low enough to turn off Q1.